# Looping of each 2 TextBoxes

Tags: vb.net

I've been thinking of on how to loop my textboxes that has an integer as a value and insert it in a listview. My textboxes starts at Textbox2.Text and ended in Textbox41.Text. The thing is I need to check each 2 textboxes (ex. textbox2 and textbox3)and insert in a listview. I dont know how to loop the other textboxes.

```
Try
   If TextBox2.Text <> Nothing And TextBox3.Text <> Nothing Then
      Pid += 1
      At = TextBox2.Text
      Bt = TextBox3.Text

      Table = ListView1.Items.Add(Pid)
      With Table
         .SubItems.Add(At)
         .SubItems.Add(Bt)
      End With

      TextBox2.Text = Nothing
      TextBox3.Text = Nothing
   End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Must be numbers!")
End Try
```

Comment: Please add more information to the question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your application is Windows Form or Web?

Comment: My application is Windows Form :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is Windows Form, this is how you can get all integer values...

```
Dim intList As New List(Of Integer)()
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If c.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
        Dim txtControl As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
        If Integer.TryParse(txtControl.Text, 0) Then
            intList.Add(Convert.toInt32(txtControl.Text))
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi. There's an error in the 4th line :) Thanks btw 

Comment: Thank you!! But there's still an error in c .. (c, 0)